# Auto complete textbox using web service

Tags: asp.net, web-services, jquery

I have created web service which I am calling from client script. But it shows an error. I can not understand where the error is coming from. I also set break points at different points both in web service and in client script but not encountered those break points. Here is the code that I have written.

Code for Class file

```
public class GetContacts
{ 
public int ID { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public GetContacts()
{
    //
    // TODO: Add constructor logic here
    //
}
public List<GetContacts> FetchContacts()
{
    List<GetContacts> ContactList = new List<GetContacts>();
    ContactList.Add(new GetContacts() { ID = 1, Name = "XXX<1111111111>" });
    ContactList.Add(new GetContacts() { ID = 2, Name = "XXX<1111111111>" });
    ContactList.Add(new GetContacts() { ID = 3, Name = "XXX<1111111111>" });
    ContactList.Add(new GetContacts() { ID = 4, Name = "XXX<1111111111>" });
    ContactList.Add(new GetContacts() { ID = 5, Name = "XXX<1111111111>" });
    ContactList.Add(new GetContacts() { ID = 6, Name = "XXX<1111111111>" });
    ContactList.Add(new GetContacts() { ID = 7, Name = "XXX<1111111111>" });
    ContactList.Add(new GetContacts() { ID = 7, Name = "XXX<1111111111>" });

    return ContactList;
}
}
```

Code for web service.

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment  the following line. 
 [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class Contacts : System.Web.Services.WebService {

public Contacts () {

    //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
    //InitializeComponent(); 
}

[WebMethod]
public string HelloWorld() {
    return "Hello World";
}
public List<GetContacts> FetchContactList(string Name)
{
    var Receipent = new GetContacts();
    var ContactDetail = Receipent.FetchContacts()
    .Where(m => m.Name.ToLower().StartsWith(Name.ToLower()));

    return ContactDetail.ToList();
}
}
```

Code for Default.aspx page

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<%--<script src="jQuery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>--%>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".tb").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "Contacts.asmx/FetchContactList",
                    data: "{ 'Name': '" + request.term + "' }",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                            return {
                                value: item.Name
                            }
                        }))
                    },
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert(textStatus);
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 2
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>
            Number</td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtNumber" runat="server" class="tb"></asp:TextBox>

            </td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Message</td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtMsg" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox></td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="btnSend" runat="server" Text="Send" onclick="btnSend_Click" /></td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Please tell me where I am making mistakes.

Comment: 1, What is the error? 2, Attach to W3WP.exe to debug the service which is running locally.

Comment: @Kiru..Its just showing "error" bt not showing what is the error..
I am new in web service so no idea about debugging web serivce. I kept break point in visual studio at web service method but the point is not being encountered.

Comment: ok I think it looks like Javascript error. You have to debug and find out the value for data which is passed when it is success. To debug jquery add debugger statement in your code and enable javascript debugging in your browser.

Comment: @Kiru. When I write something in textbox, it shows "undefined" in error. What should I do..?

Comment: Do I need to create/add reference to my web service or I can use it directly just as normal class?

Comment: I tried your code, Add [WebMethod] attribute to your FetchContactList

Comment: Glad it worked. Please mark your answer if you are happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add [WebMethod] attribute to your FetchContactList

Answer (score 0):

have you implemented the attributes

[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]

[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]

See this for complete reference
http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx